# Page Break in SSRS Not Working When Tablix Row Continues Into Next Page

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report where the user wants the "Raw Materials" section to be on a new page. Normally this works, but when the previous section, "Operations", continues from the page it started on, the page break does not occur for the Raw Materials section. Each section is in a separate tablix row within the same tablix.

How can I make this happen?

I have played with the KeepTogether and PageBreak options, as well as adding a SubReport with a PageBreak before the Raw Materials section and have seen little results.

I have also tried using rectangles between each row and setting page breaks there to no avail.
[image: Report Design]

Comment: I can't visualise what your report looks like but try adding a row above the raw section and inserting a rectangle with a page break set on it. Page breaks in subreports are generally ignored in my experience. If that doesn't help, edit your question and show a screen shot of the report design and any relevant setting you have attempted.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Will do!